# How to upload zope site on my ftp?

Tags: python, frameworks, zope, zope.interface

Hey, I'd like to know how to upload my zope site on my ftp. I have a domain, and I like to upload it, like a upload normal files on my ftp.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can upload zope the same way you would upload anything else, but it's not suitable for deploying on many shared webhosts as many of them would not like you running the zope process due to the ammount of resources it can consume

You are best off trying to find a webhost that supports zope or to use a VPS

Comment: where is the files so I can upload it. I've installed it on c:, and there is a folder there called Zope-Instance. How am I gonna link to the a page, or a folder there? Thanks.

Comment: I'm with gribbler; Zope isn't particularly designed for what you seem to describe.  It's not just having files in the right place (which is likely to be difficult; Zope isn't packaged for *that* kind of installation); someone at the hosting company also has to kick off a process or processes.  There must be an easier solution for you.

Comment: @rogcg, Why don't you try a normal CSM like Wordpress or Drupal which are easily deployable through FTP?